# Filter an array with many parameters "like an SQL query"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to filter objects in array.

It works with one parameters

```
@usersc = @usersb.select { |user| user.need_appartment?  }
```

but i would like use more parameters than in SQL/ActiveRecord :

```
(need_bedrooms_min >= :nb_bedrooms_min) AND (budget_amount BETWEEN :budget_min AND :budget_max) AND ((need_surface_min BETWEEN :surface_min AND :surface_max)  OR (need_surface_max BETWEEN :surface_min AND :surface_max))"+req,{nb_bedrooms_min: params[:nb_bedrooms_min], budget_min: params[:budget_min], budget_max: params[:budget_max],surface_min: params[:surface_min], surface_max: params[:surface_max]}).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

I dont find the solution... Anyone can help me ?

F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select` does exactly what you need with as many parameters as you might want:

```
@usersb.select do |user|
  user.need_bedrooms_min >= params[:nb_bedrooms_min].to_i &&
  (params[:budget_min].to_i..params[:budget_max].to_i).include? user.budget_amount &&
  ((params[:surface_min].to_i..params[:surface_max].to_i).include? user.need_surface_min ||
   (params[:surface_min].to_i..params[:surface_max].to_i).include? user.need_surface_max)
end
```

Or, more cleanly:

```
class User
  def needs_apartment?(params)
    budget_min, budget_max, surface_min, surface_max, nb_bedrooms_min = 
        %w{budget_min budget_max surface_min surface_max nb_bedrooms_min}.map{|k| params[k.to_sym].to_i}
    budget_range = budget_min..budget_max
    surface_range = surface_min..surface_max

    need_bedrooms_min >= nb_bedrooms_min &&
      budget_range.include? budget_amount &&
      (surface_range.include?(need_surface_min) || surface_range.include?(need_surface_max))
  end
end

@usersb.select{|user| user.needs_apartment?(params)}
```

Comment: Or if it doesn't belong in a model method, toss it in a lambda (`the_ones_i_want = lambda { ... }`) and `@usersb.select(&the_ones_i_want)` instead. Or stash the logic in a controller method and `@usersb.select(&method(:the_ones_i_want))` if that makes more sense.